# PHP - How To Make Pages For Overflowing Foreach?

Tags: php, foreach

Sorry for the rather unhelpful title, I am trying to make multiple pages for my foreach statement, as it reaches to a database with 100's of rows. Would I limit the query 1,30 for the first page, then 31-60 the second? If so how would I code that?

Answer (score 1):

```
$totalRows = 100;// Total rows
$perPage = 30;
$pages = ceil($totalRows/$perPage);
for ($i = 0; $i<=$pages; $i++)
{
    $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT %s, %s", $i*$perPage, $perPage);
    // Execute
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Queries can carry a significant overhead, so don't do multiple queries.  Rather, do a single query, then use PHP to break the results up as you wish.  You can use a loop counter along with the % operator to check if it's time to do a break.

For instance, if you are looping through results and your loop variable is $i, then you can do:

```
if ( $i > 0 && $i % 30 == 0 ) {
    // Breaking action here ...
}
```

To detect every 30th iteration of your loop and implement your logic.

Comment: `Queries can carry a significant overhead, so don't do multiple queries.` Though I agree that one query is better than 2 do not forget about memory. If records are big and there a lot of them (depends on  table size and amount you try to pick) you would run out of memory and you queries can slow down a lot. eg. It is fast to pick 10 rows from 50,000,000 table but it can be very slow to pick 1000.

Comment: True.  The OP will have to check the performance.  My experience with multiple queries has been that the performance degrades so badly that I would take the risk with the memory rather than the performance hit.  In my experience, adding even an additional query can drag performance down into unusable territory.